# double conversion value error in c#

Tags: c#, double

```
double deg=90;
double two= 2* System.Math.PI;
double rad=(two)*(deg/360);
```

the original value when calculating manually ,rad is 1.5707963267948966 but  rad shows when debugging is 1.5707963705062866  what is reason for this and how do i fix it.but correct answer is manual calculation answer only......

Here are the numbers for easier comparison:

```
1.5707963267948966
1.5707963705062866
         --------- <-- differences
```

during the debug i put the pointer in right side that means calculation side it shows correct answer but the error happen when storing that value to rad.

is anybody help for me.i need it.

Comment: Can you post a short, but complete, program that exhibits the problem in question? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: When you say "manual calculation", do you mean you're doing this with a calculator of some sort? As others are pointing out, pi has an infinite decimal expansion, so any "exact" answer you're giving in your question is *already* an approximation.

Comment: The difference is one part in a hundred million. What possible engineering application could you be performing that needs precision to one part in a hundred million?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rounding errors happen; it isn't infinite precision. You will have to test whether values are *suitably* close - don't just test for equality. In *some* cases you might also see subtle differences by applying the operators in a different sequence, so you don't swamp small numbers with magnitude.

Comment: i need exact value for my further calculation so only

Comment: You need the *exact* value of maths involving Pi? I hope you've got plenty of RAM... You'll need to use specialized libraries to do that; `double` (IEEE 754) simply can't do it.

Comment: thank for u comment mr.marc what is that specialized libraries for this

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Do you mean "I hope you've got infinite RAM"?

Comment: @Residuum: Pi is a number that has, as far as humanity knows, an infinite number of places after the decimal place.

Comment: @R. Bemrose - not quite: it is a number that humanity **knows** has an infinite number of places after the decimal point. It is a *relatively* simple proof, IIRC.

Comment: @Marc, the proof of irrationality is pretty straightforward, here's a nice one: http://www.mathlesstraveled.com/?p=548.  The proof that pi is not merely irrational but transcendental is trickier; begin by proving that e is transcendental and then the result for pi follows from Euler's identity.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Or the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem gets you both `e` and `π`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a decimal type rather than double. It's due to floating point precision.

Comment: decimal is also only approximate... but it is approximated in different ways (and has a few more bits to play with). It is also noticeably slower.

Comment: The Decimal type should be used with things like currency calculations. When doing scientific / mathematical calculations, Double should be used, unless you need better precision, then a specialised library is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `decimal` value, which is more accurate than `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Double, float and decimal are really your only standard options. If they are not precise enough for your needs, you will need to create your own type and provide it a means of storing these high precision values and its own operators for performing mathematical functions.

You'll notice the double type is accurate to 7 places, the decimal type will be accurate for slightly more. If you want greater precision than that, you will need to come up with an algorithm for computing it and storing it.

Comment: The double type is not accurate to only 7 places, more like 16. The problem in the question is not because of imprecise double data type being used. What you notices is that his question seems to indicate that the precision is only 7 digits, but that is wrong.

Comment: I know, but in his example it was only accurate to his calculation to 7 digits likely because of the differences in PI and order of operations. Point I was making was that the standard types should be good enough to accomplish the task, if they're not a new one just needs to be made up to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I can't reproduce what you're seeing.

I did this:

using System;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double deg = 90;
            double two = 2 * System.Math.PI;
            double rad = (two) * (deg / 360); 

            Console.Out.WriteLine(rad);
        }
    }
}
```

And I got this output:

```
1.5707963267949
```

When hovering over the `rad` variable when on a breakpoint on the WriteLine line, I saw the following value in the tooltip

```
1.5707963267948966
```

Where/how did you see that other value?

The difference above is probably due to me not specifying the precision in my write-call, so perhaps I could get all the digits there as well. I'm certainly not seeing the second value you mention.

Comment: i did this in windows form apllication

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a short, but complete, program that shows us the problem? Since I can't reconstruct the problem I'm willing to bet the code in question isn't really as simple as the one you've placed in the question. In other words, I am willing to bet there is something you're not telling us. My guess is that you have fallen into the normal trap of "simplifying" the code so that we can understand it, and in the process, you've "simplified" away the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good description of floating-point arithmetic:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)